# JScrollPane Troubles

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have been trying for the last 4 days, scouring this website, trying to find answers on how to fix my JScrollPane problem. I am not viewing all of the content and cannot scroll down.

I have tried adding the Component to the JScrollPane only (worked but not all the way), setting the preferred size of the JScrollPane (didn't work due to me having a null layout), alongside countless others.

Here's the code that directly affects the area of the window that I am concerned with:

```
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Thing Maker");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    eastPanel = new JPanel();
    eastPanel.setBounds(400, 0, 400, 612);
    contentPane.add(eastPanel);
    eastPanel.setLayout(null);

    buildings = new JPanel();
    //buildings.setBounds(2, 2, 400, 612);
    buildings.setLayout(null);

    buildingPanels[0] = new BuildingPanel(0, 0, 0);
    buildings.add(buildingPanels[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < buildingPanels.length; i++) {
        buildingPanels[i] = new BuildingPanel(i, buildingPanels[i-1]);
        buildings.add(buildingPanels[i]);
    }

    JScrollPane buildingsScroll = new JScrollPane(buildings, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    buildingsScroll.setBounds(2, 2, 400, 612);
    buildingsScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setSize(10, buildingsScroll.getHeight());

    eastPanel.add(buildingsScroll);
```

The BuildingPanel, an extension of Swing's JPanel, is very complicated and I don't think it directly affects the window, since it's a JScrollPane problem. However, it is very similar to the JPanel eastPanel.

Thank you.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: `JScrollPane` relies on the preferred size of the component it's showing in order to determine if it should show the scroll bars or not, be removing the layout managers and relying on `null` layouts, you've removed this functionality and therefore broken the API.  The Swing API is designed around the use of layout managers and frankly, you'd be mad not to take advantage of the thousands of developer hours that went into creating them ... or spend millions of your hours reinventing a wheel which isn't broken

Comment: I strongly second all that @MadProgrammer states above, but will add that in the future when you ask about similar problems, don't post a code snippet and don't post your entire code. Instead create and post a [mcve], a runnable testable **small** program that we can modify and hopefully help you correct.